# Issue with SQL query within a bash script

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I'm having an issue with a query, when I run it from the command line I have no problems, but from a script it expands the script in a strange way.

My query:

```
QUERY[1]="SELECT users.username AS \"User name\"FROM mytable WHERE creation_date > '${BEGIN}' AND creation_date < '${END}'"
```

The call from the script:

```
$(mysql -hmyhost -uuser -pmypass -Dmydb -B -e "${QUERY[${query}]}")
```

and I get a:

> -bash: User: command not found

Any idea whats going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(mysql -hmyhost -uuser -pmypass -Dmydb -B -e "${QUERY[${query}]}")
```

I think you don't need to place it under command substitution:

```
mysql -hmyhost -uuser -pmypass -Dmydb -B -e "${QUERY[${query}]}"
```

It causes the output of `mysql ...` to be executed as well thus showing the error `User: command not found`.

Answer (score 0):

if you just add a line on a script like this:
$(somecommand)
The output of the command 'somecommand' will be used by the shell as a command.
What you probably want to do is:
output=$(somecommand)